# GIT CD "Laravel + React" application

Tags: reactjs, laravel, git, github

I have an application that uses Laravel as backend and React as frontend

The two applications are stored in separate repositories.

In the local environment, I serve the Laravel application with "php artisan:serve" and the React application with "npm run start".
The two applications communicate with each other through POST/GET APIs.

Now I want to create a "deploy" repository.

The deploy repository should have two folders:

- backend (containing Laravel application)
- frontend (containing React application)

I want that every time a merge is made on the main branch of one of the two repos (backend or frontend) the changes are pushed to the deploy repository too.

The deploy repo will take care of building the app and eventually build a docker image.

Is this possible?

There are better ways/patterns to achieve what I want?

Comment: Why you want to deploy backend with frontend? Keep it separately, they shouldn't know about each other

Comment: That would mean, that if you change one of two repo's, both will get deployed. IMy question would be: if you want to deploy them together, than why would you use 2 repo's?

Comment: I wanted to do this because I have a customer that doesn't want a cloud solution. I still need to keep Backend and Frontend separately becasue Backend is used for other projects too. So my idea was to create this deploy repo from wich I can pull a docker image every time I need to update the app on the customer server